# git ssh: conect to host port 22 bad file number; can not pull

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I just installed a fresh Windows 7 Home Premium on my PC and wanted to reestablish my conection to a Git server. Therefore I copied my old .shh folder from the old installation into C:\users\user.ssh including a id_rsa, id_rsa.pub, known_hosts and a key.ppk. (everything was working with the old system). Afterwards I tryed connecting via Putty and Git Bash both failed.  Putty just gave a cryptik "connection timed out" Git Bash returned:

`ssh: conncet to host xxx.xx.xx.xx port 22: bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Googeling did not return anything really usefull since the port can not be blocked by the server. I can not change to a https conection and need to use ssh. Turning off the windows firewall did also not help.

I hope someone can help me with this, kind regards,
mhwh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved it self - I do not know why, but now everything is working properly, in the meantime Skype and some Windwos updates have been installed but I am not shure how this might affect the git system...

Answer (score -2):

I have also encountered such problems. The solution is to start the Windows Update Service:

[image]

[image]